# Divide each location equally between employee excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, mathematical-optimization, divide

if any one can help me at the following:

I have 1000 accounts with different locations. (150 for ER location, 200 for GP location, etc)
I need to distribute each location equally between each employee, but some of the employee will take only 1 location based on the number I need to give them.

For example: I have 5 employee as total
3 will take all location
1 will take only 1 location with 200 amount (200 is changeable)
1 will take only 1 location with 100 amount (100 is changeable)

But before that I need to ask how are the employees I will distribute for them and which clinic they will have? and I need the amount calculate automatically.

Any one can help?!!!

Comment: I would set this up and use the Solver.

Comment: Can you explain please!!

Comment: What does this have to do with statistical distributions?  I'm having trouble understanding your description but it sounds like resource allocation, not probability/statistics.

Comment: Look at your constraints and the thing you want to optimize either max or min. Solver will adjust changing cells to meet the constraints if it can find a solution.